# Access Single Bid Price From Column Using Python and YFinance

Tags: yfinance

Thank you in advance for your time and attention.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am dabbling in both options trading and computer programming.  Little experience in either.

What I am trying to do is to use Python, with NumPy and the YFinance module, to send Yahoo an alphabetical series of stock ticker symbols along with a request to provide the BID price for the current CALL option contract that is the highest STRIKE price lower than the current price of the stock, subject to price filtering criteria.  I want to get that single BID and do some calculations with it.

For example, if XYZ stock is selling for $10.04 and highest CALL option STRIKE price for XYZ lower than $10.04 is $10.00 , I would like to get the BID price for the next-expiring $10 CALL option.

With the code below, I have a lot of it working.  I send in the list of ticker symbols and Yahoo filters them by my pricing criteria and returns the symbols that meet my pricing criteria. I can also get Yahoo to return calls limited to the next expiration date.  The call data is returned as some sort of list-like, array-like structure.  I can make it list a column of BIDS (covering ALL of the STRIKE prices).  I can make it list a column of STRIKES.  I can make it print both of these columns.

But what I can't seem to do, is to get this damned computer to select the particular BID from the BID column that matches a particular STRIKE price from the STRIKE column.  I see that the Column looks like a list or an array with elements.

I just want the program to find the right STRIKE price and to use that value to get the BID that matches the STRIKE price in the same row of (list? array? table?) whatever is made with calls = op.get_calls(x) by YFinance. In the output (posted at the bottom) this would be the BID (0.12) from element [03] in the row with STRIKE price (15.0)  Once I have that BID, I want to store into a variable and go dance naked and live happy.

Here is the code I wrote:

from yahoo_fin import options as op

import yfinance as yf
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

`# Open list of ticker symbols from a text file`

with open("WeeklyList.txt", "r") as file:
 # Read list to readline without new line`

```
readline=file.read().splitlines()
```

`# Roll through list of symbols`

for x in readline:

```
ticker = yf.Ticker(x).info # get Stock info
previous_close_price = ticker['regularMarketPreviousClose']
floor = int(previous_close_price) # Calculate highest option less than stock price
margin = previous_close_price - floor # Calculate difference between stock and option price
```

`# Limit returns of ticker symbols to stocks that are within 5 cents of strike price`

```
if previous_close_price < 50:
`
```

#` **Here is the code I can't make work right** ``

```
    if margin < 0.05:
        print(x)
        print('Previous Close Price:', previous_close_price)
        strike_price = floor
        print(strike_price)
        calls = op.get_calls(x)
        print([calls.Bid], [calls.Strike])
```

`# If I can make the section above work, I will be able to make this section work`   
elif margin> 0.49 and margin < 0.56:
strike_price = floor + 0.50
print(x)
print('Previous Close Price:', previous_close_price)

Here is a sample o the output of the program.  Ticker symbol printed first.  Then previous close price. The BID column. Finally STRIKE column.

BEKE
Previous Close Price: 15.0
15
[0     2.12
1     0.72
2     0.32
3     0.12
4     0.02
5     0.00
6     0.00
7     0.00
8     0.00
9     0.00
10    0.00
11    0.00
12    0.00
Name: Bid, dtype: float64] [0     12.5
1     14.0
2     14.5
3     15.0
4     15.5
5     16.0
6     16.5
7     17.0
8     17.5
9     18.0
10    18.5
11    19.0
12    19.5
Name: Strike, dtype: float64]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgFYS.png)

Have not tried blowing up the computer.